# I want the new logcat to work in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logcat, android-logcat, android-sdk-tools

As I've updated eclipse, ADT and everything to the latest, the new logcat in the eclipse doesn't show the logs of my connected device. It simply shows `logcat read: Invalid argument`. However, the "*Logcat (Deprecated)*" one works perfectly and shows my logs.

I want the new logcat to work. I presume that adb cannot handle requesting for logs with more than 1 concurrent connections to my device. So is there any way to stop the deprecated logcat from working so that this **might** fix the new logcat?